# Access 2010 VBA Run-time error '3265' Item not found in this collection

Tags: vba, ms-access

This is a strange one as this code worked fine (some thirty or more runs) Saturday and yesterday but kicks out with "Item not found in this collection." invariably today:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("quyPartRpt")
qdf.Sql = Replace(qdf.Sql, "plugtable", txtVigilTable)
If optGp1 = 1 Then
    qdf.Sql = Replace(qdf.Sql, "WHERE v.[fldUserName] = v.[fld.UserName]", "WHERE v.[fldChurch/Parish] = Forms!frmGpReport1!cmbChurch")
    qdf.Parameters("Forms!frmGpReport1![cmbChurch]") = Forms!frmGpReport1![cmbChurch]
Else
    If IsNull(Forms!frmGpReport1![cmbCouncil]) Then
        qdf.Sql = Replace(qdf.Sql, "WHERE v.[fldUserName] = v.[fld.UserName]", "WHERE v.[fldGroup] = Forms!frmGpReport1![cmbGroup]")
        qdf.Parameters("Forms!frmGpReport1![cmbGroup]") = Forms!frmGpReport1![cmbGroup]
    Else
        qdf.Sql = Replace(qdf.Sql, "WHERE v.[fldUserName] = v.[fld.UserName]", "WHERE v.[fldGroup] = Forms!frmGpReport1![cmbGroup] AND v.[fldCouncil/Court] = Forms!frmGpReport1![cmbCouncil]")
        qdf.Parameters("Forms!frmGpReport1![cmbGroup]") = Forms!frmGpReport1![cmbGroup]
        MsgBox Forms!frmGpReport1![cmbCouncil]
        qdf.Parameters("Forms!frmGpReport1![cmbCouncil]") = Forms!frmGpReport1![cmbCouncil]
    End If
End If

MsgBox qdf.Sql
Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset
```

(Truncated as rest is irrelevant and works.)

The line  "qdf.Parameters("Forms!frmGpReport1![cmbCouncil]") = Forms!frmGpReport1![cmbCouncil]" is the one that always kicks out the error.

The line immediately above it ("MsgBox Forms!frmGpReport1![cmbCouncil]") gives me the correct value of the contents of cmbCouncil so I cannot for the life of me understand why VBA can't find it when setting up the query.

Any ideas at all would be most appreciated.

(The If,Else is to deal with the fact that some of our organizations -- Knights of Columbus, for example -- are organized into local councils or courts and most are not.  I want to be able to report accordingly.)

Thanks.

Comment: Double-check the values pulled from your comboboxes.

Comment: "Double-check the values pulled from your comboboxes."  <br/> I have repeatedly; they are always exactly the same as the values I selected in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Quite often Access SQL doesn't like anonymous parameters and gets confused. So, you may have to be more explicit, building SQL like this, where you declare the parameters and their data type:

```sql
Parameters
    cmbChurch Text,
    cmbGroup Text,
    cmbCouncil Text;
Select 
    ...
From
    PlugTable
Where
    v.[fldChurch/Parish] = cmbChurch
    And
    v.[fldGroup] = cmbGroup
    And
    v.[fldCouncil/Court] = cmbCouncil
```

And then:

```vb
qdf.Parameters("cmbChurch").Value = Forms!frmGpReport1![cmbChurch].Value
qdf.Parameters("cmbGroup").Value = Forms!frmGpReport1![cmbGroup].Value
qdf.Parameters("cmbCouncil").Value = Forms!frmGpReport1![cmbCouncil].Value
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Show the text of msgbox qdf.sql
2. Since (you believe) the data is correct

   ```
   MsgBox Forms!frmGpReport1![cmbCouncil]
   ```

... it follows that the problem is in the other part of the statement

```
qdf.Parameters("Forms!frmGpReport1![cmbCouncil]")
```

Normally, this is because you've used the wrong qdf or parameter.

3. Since (you believe) the qdf hasn't changed since last week ... it follows that the compiled form of the qdf has become corrupted.  Delete and re-create the qdf. If that doesn't help, copy the database into a new database.

Comment: I really thought that might have it!  While waiting for an answer, I tried "Compact and Repair Database," which had the effect of extending the same problem to [cmbChurch] and [cmbGroup], not at all what I'd hoped.  <br/> So then I created a new database and copied everything into it, with no effect.  Not too sure how exactly to delete and recreate the qdf in such a way as to force a recompile, I deleted the entire sub and copied it into a text editor, saved and closed the database, reopened it, copied the sub back from the text editor.  Which fixed the problem with [cmbChurch] only.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand Gustav's answer (still don't) but it put me on the right track.

I didn't want to dim cmbChurch etc. as Text since they are already comboboxes formatted as text; but it did occur to me that it might be more convenient to create variables, set them equal to the comboboxes, and then feed them into the query, thus:

```
    Dim vChurch As String
    Dim vGroup As String
    Dim vCouncil As String
   . . . . . 
vChurch = IIf((Not IsNull(Me.cmbChurch)),   Me.cmbChurch, "")
vGroup = IIf((Not IsNull(Me.cmbGroup)), Me.cmbGroup, "")
vCouncil = IIf((Not IsNull(Me.cmbCouncil)), Me.cmbCouncil, "")
MsgBox "vChurch = " & vChurch & vbCrLf & "vGroup = " & vGroup & vbCrLf & "vCouncil = " & vCouncil
If optGp1 = 1 Then
    qdf.Sql = Replace(qdf.Sql, "WHERE v.[fldUserName] = v.[fld.UserName]", "WHERE v.[fldChurch/Parish] = Forms!frmGpReport1![cmbChurch]")
    MsgBox qdf.Sql
    qdf.Parameters("Forms!frmGpReport1![cmbChurch]") = vChurch
Else
    If (vCouncil = "") Then
        qdf.Sql = Replace(qdf.Sql, "WHERE v.[fldUserName] = v.[fld.UserName]", "WHERE v.[fldGroup] = Forms!frmGpReport1![cmbGroup]")
        MsgBox qdf.Sql
        qdf.Parameters("Forms!frmGpReport1![cmbGroup]") = vGroup
    Else
        qdf.Sql = Replace(qdf.Sql, "WHERE v.[fldUserName] = v.[fld.UserName]", "WHERE v.[fldGroup] = Forms!frmGpReport1![cmbGroup] AND v.[fldCouncil/Court] = Forms!frmGpReport1![cmbCouncil]")
        MsgBox qdf.Sql
        qdf.Parameters("Forms!frmGpReport1![cmbGroup]") = vGroup
        qdf.Parameters("Forms!frmGpReport1![cmbCouncil]") = vCouncil
    End If
End If
```

That pretty much did it.

Call me happy camper!

Comment: But I can't figure out how to indicate that Gustav's answer was useful.  There's something in the help files that I'm either not seeing or not understanding.